# Replace part of href with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've read the other questions about this same topic, and I feel like I understand what to do, but it's not working.

I have two domains, out of necessity. On one specific page, I'm trying to update the links so that they point to the second domain. It functions if I just loop through every 'a' element, but not if I try to match specific links.  I left my first attempt commented out, I'm not sure which method is better.

This function gets called if one is on that particular page, but are from a different country. I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

I thought that this.href should get the full, qualified URL but it doesn't seem to be doing so.

```
function updateLinksToUSAstore() {

  $('a[href*="manitobahdev.myshopify.com"]').each(function() {
//    $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href').replace('manitobahdev.myshopify.com', 'manitobahdev-us.myshopify.com')); 
      this.href = this.href.replace('manitobahdev', 'manitobahdev-us'); 
  });
  var CountryName = localStorage.getItem('CountryName');    
  // Change currently selected country text
  $('#country-label, #country-label-mobile').text(CountryName);
}
```

Comment: The only way I see that not working is if `$('a[href*="manitobahdev.myshopify.com"]')` returns nothing. Have you logged the array that returns?

Comment: Can you show us some `a` elements? I just tried a quick [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kc6zLdpe/1/), and it's working properly. Make sure that you're not using the cache while testing your javascript.

Comment: @Wikiti The problem seems to be that the links are relative, but shouldn't this.href get the full URL?

Comment: @Patrick Yes, `href` should return the whole url. Perhaps there is a problem or systax error while building the DOM tree. Anyways, maybe [this library](https://medialize.github.io/URI.js/) can be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
var href = null;
$("a").each(function()
{
  href = $(this).attr("href");
  if(href.contains("manitobahdev.myshopify.com"))
  {
    $(this).attr("href", href.replace("manitobahdev.myshopify.com", "manitobahdev-us.myshopify.com"));
  }
});
```

I'm on mobile right now, so i was not able to test this. Sorry if it doesn't work.
Plus, i don't really understand why you'd want to edit only the manitobahdev part to manitobahdev-us, since both end with myshopify.com

Comment: In this instance, they are two different subdomains, thus it would link to a second store. The actual live URLs are different.

Answer (score 0):

> May be it will help you.

```js
//get all selector
var celem=jQuery('a[href*="manitobahdev.myshopify.com"]');

for(var i=0;i<celem.length;i++){ 
  console.log('====== BEFORE ===='); 
  //get each href of selector 
var ele=jQuery(celem[i]).prop('href'); 
console.log(ele);
 
  jQuery(celem[i]).prop('href',ele.replace('manitobahdev','manitobahdev-us')); 
  
console.log('====== AFTER ===');                           
ele=jQuery(celem[i]).prop('href'); 
console.log(ele);                             
                           
                           }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id='test1' href="manitobahdev.myshopify.com/ABC">Test 1</a>
<a  id='test2' href="http://manitobahdev.myshopify.com/ZAXC">Test 2</a>
<a  id='test3' href="manitobahdev.myshopify.com/USER/1">Test 3</a>
```